# Positioning Button over Image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard, constraints

I have a full screen ImageView (margins constraints) with an Image in "Aspect Fit Mode" and I need to have a button to be over a specific part of that image on all devices.

I have tried to put constraints in different ways, but without any good result.

I hope someone could help me.

Here you can find a screenshot of what I want:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/krl5rp47w2rxl0g/Schermata%202015-09-12%20alle%2015.15.43.png?dl=0]

The yellow block is the button and I want it to be over the shoulder for any screen size.

This is iOS 8.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what constraints have you tried? What does the final output have to look like?

Comment: What's the problem again? Is yellow block the button you want to position so that it's always appear on the shoulder of the body in any cases (iPhone */iPad *, portrait/landscape modes?)

Comment: Can you please tell about the devices is it universal or just iPhone

Comment: Yes the yellow block is the button and I want it to appear over the shoulder in portrait and landscape for iPad only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have embedded your image in your question. You will be able to do this yourself in the future using the image button by clicking [edit] or pressing Cntrl+G..

Answer (score 5):

Try proportional Constraints.
Add the following 4 constraints to your button (values are not exact)

1. Give your button a proportional width constraint with ImageView. So button width will become 10% of ImageView width for example.
2. Give your button a proportional height constraint with ImageView. So button height will become 10% of ImageView height for example.
3. Now center y of button is 40% of center y of ImageView(value is approx.) Try different value to get your goal
4. Now center x of button is 80% of center x of ImageView.

Apple recommend using proportional constraints. Try to change the percent values slightly to fit the button on shoulder. Once you fit the button on shoulder with these constraints It will look fine on all device .
Thanks

Comment: I have already tried, but it doesn't work because the constraints must be proportional to the UIImage, not to the UIImageView

Comment: I edit my answer. I test it and it work fine both in portrait and landscape modes. first bound your ImageView(image) from all four sides to parent view and then apply these constraints to your button (proportional to image).

Comment: How to give promotional width? I do not see width in % option.

Comment: @deepakssn : Control and drag from one element to another element, select equal width. Now change the multiplier to 0.8 (which means element1 width is 80% to element2)

Comment: Thanks @Irfan. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

If both element on the same view, just drag the button bellow the image in the View Controller Scene, and you are done.[image]

Comment: This is not correct. The button will not remain in that location on all devices / orientations without constraints.

Answer (score 0):

just have to add center vertically & center horizontally and equal height and equal width to image and then play with multipliers to make it where you want.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer doesn't really give enough detail to be useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.